# TSMP77000 IR Receiver Code

Tags: controls, embedded, led, pwm, infrared

I'm using tsmp77000 IR Sensor module for air conditioner remote control system.
[datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/82478/tsmp77000.pdf)
I instructed remote controller device of the air conditioner to sensor module and i saw voltage outputs(active low) on the oscilloscope. Then, i need to transmit this signals with IR transmitter led for control air conditioner. But, there is voltage outputs, there isn't frequency graph. How to i convert to pwm output of this signal? Frequency, duty cycle?

And I saw frequency value on the ossiloscope, but it is 833Hz. Whereas,range of IR receiver sensor module is 20-60kHz.

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.sbprojects.com/knowledge/ir/index.php
may or may not apply here, but IR remotes are generally a slower protocol that uses the tens of khz as a carrier.  kinda like am modulation but with a square wave and you are not generating a wave so much as a series of pulses.  so if you want to re-transmit or create a new command then you need both the slower protocol signal, then AND that with the carrier.

Comment: What you are seeing on the scope is a demodulated output.  Crudely speaking, you need to generate output at the modulation carrier frequency for the periods of time that the demodulator output was active.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good explanation of how IR remote signals work by Adafruit: https://learn.adafruit.com/ir-sensor/ir-remote-signals

The 833Hz you are seeing on the oscilloscope are most likely the "wide" bands. If you zoom in, you should see that each pulse is actually made up of many, faster, PWM pulses.

Your best bet will be determining the frequency of the fast IR pulses, setting your PWM pin to that frequency, and then manually enable/disable the PWM pin for the appropriate time intervals, as per the oscilloscope reading.